# how to install sublime text indent xml in sublime 3

Tags: xml, formatting, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am trying to install https://github.com/alek-sys/sublimetext_indentxml in sublime text 3.
I read

> In Sublime Text 3 - clone project from Github into Packages folder.

Doesn't seem to work.

I am not sure where the Packages folder is.

Comment: I have it "installed", but I don't see anything referencing usage after it's installed. I can't find it in the menus, despite files existing in the directories referenced in the answers below. Any helpful hints re: how to use this thing once it's installed?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

None of the above answers worked for me as they appeared to be missing a crucial 'step' to the process (step 2 below). This is how I got it to install for me in Windows using Sublime Text 3:

1. Install Package Control (Tools > Install Package Control...)
2. Open Package Control (Ctrl+Shift+P) and type 'Package Control: Install Package' and then press Enter.
3. Sublime will attempt to load any custom repositories then offer a list of packages available.
4. At this point, I was able to successfully search for 'indent xml' and have it appear in the list and install by pressing Enter with it selected.

Comment: There is nothing in package control that is called `indent xml`

Comment: It is called IndentX and works as @1247p describes bellow.

Comment: Dimitri, I think you missed to do #2 like me. These steps work

Comment: indent xml is already added in sublime text 3. no need to add. select all xml code, press (Ctrl+Shift+P), type indent xml and hit enter

Comment: @Shrirang Nothing appears typing "indent xml"

Answer (score 78):

The most error free way, is to

1. Install the `Package Control` First
2. <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then type **Install Package** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Type **Indent XML** and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

### To Use:

1. Open the `XML` file that you need to reformat
2. <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> then type **Indent XML**
3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Your Document will then update.

For information how to install the package control please see:

[https://packagecontrol.io/installation](https://packagecontrol.io/installation#content)

And

[https://packagecontrol.io/docs/usage](https://packagecontrol.io/docs/usage#content)

Comment: I've done everything in the directions you referenced, closed the app and relaunched. Once I've got it "installed", how do I get the XML to indent?

Comment: @Adrian Package Control is a GUI package manager, once install go in Sublime Text 3 and click on the preference Tab, then click on Package Control, install package, after type indentXml

Comment: step 2 doesn't find anything like indent xml

Comment: @cja I'm having the same issue. Nothing comes up when I type 'indent' or 'indent xml' or 'indentXml'

Comment: both of you what operating systems do youo use? i haven't got a mac or linux only tested on windows

Comment: Mine only listed it until I installed it. You could try Package Control > List Packages, and see if it is already installed.

Comment: Indent XML can not be found until you choose Install Package first

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Mac, go to the menu as follows:

<kbd>Sublime Text</kbd> `-->`
<kbd>Preferences</kbd> `-->`
<kbd>Package Control</kbd> `-->`
<kbd>Install Package</kbd>

When the list box opens, type `indent xml` ( or a different package `indentx` ).

Once the package is installed, <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Then choose `indent xml` to automatically format your file.

Comment: THE BEST ANSWER EVER..

Answer (score 13):

The location is system dependent, but are located at:

- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`
- Windows: `%APPDATA%/Sublime Text 3/Packages/`
- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/`

Answer (score 13):

Try this (for Windows only):

Open Sublime Text 3

**Ctrl+Shift+P**

Type: **Package Control: Install Package**

Then lastly type: **indent XML**

after installing the package open an XML file then press **Ctrl+K** next press **Ctrl+F** or you can go to **Selection->Format->Auto Indent**.

Comment: Format -> auto indent saved me

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Package Control (Preference > Package Control) to install Indent XML.
2. Then you can run the package by hitting <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and then typing indent xml

Answer (score 0):

I was able to format XML without installing anything via Package Control.

1. Rename the file to end with `.xml`
2. Open the file into SublimeText
3. Select all
4. Right click -> HTML/CSS/JS Prettify -> Prettify Code

Answer (score 0):

It works by manually copying the contents of the zip file under ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Need to make sure the package `Indentor.sublime-package` is installed.

**Install the Package Control First**

Ctl + shift + P then type Install Package and press Enter

- Type Indentor and press Enter

Ctl + shift + P then type Install Package and press Enter

- Type Indent XML and press Enter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aAPz.png)

To Use:
Open the XML file that you need to reformat
Ctl + shift + P then type Indent XML
Press Enter